# Active Report 10 : label size increase when textbox size increase

Tags: c#, activereports

I make table from label and textbox attached to label.
When textbox size increase then label size not increasing.

Comment: can we see a sample code of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SectionReport label and textbox controls, label control does not grow automatically.   you can use a textbox control for both your field and label to get the same behavior.

Grapecity ActiveReports Team

[Grapecity](https://www.grapecity.com/activereports)